# Graph networkx from python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, networkx

I need help with networkX or any other graph lib in python. 
I have dictionary with keys and for every key a few value:

```
{nan: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'BBDD': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'AAAD': array(['BBDD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'AAFF': array(['AAAD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'MMCC': array(['AAAD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'KKLL': array(['AAFF', 'MMCC', 'AAAD', 'BBDD', nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'GGHH': array(['KKLL', 'NI4146', 'MMCC', nan, nan, nan, nan],dtype=object), ...}
```

Now my question is, how can I put data from this dict to graph, where keys would be nodes and values would be edges. Which way is the best for iteration through dict?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from([1,2,3,4,5])
g.add_edge(1,2)
g.add_edge(4,2)
g.add_edge(3,5)
g.add_edge(2,3)
g.add_edge(5,4)

nx.draw(g,with_labels=True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

It should be something like this, but with other data

Comment: Why do you have a numpy array of strings instead of using a regular list of strings?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you talking about, I'm a total beginner. But I guess what you think, that's because I got the first dataframe and then I've transformed dataframe to dict. @IgnacioVergaraKausel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you start with

```
d = {nan: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'BBDD': array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'AAAD': array(['BBDD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'AAFF': array(['AAAD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'MMCC': array(['AAAD', nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object),
 'KKLL': array(['AAFF', 'MMCC', 'AAAD', 'BBDD', nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)}
```

Then you can use `add_nodes_from` like this:

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(d.keys())
```

and `add_edges_from` like this:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    g.add_edges_from(([(k, t) for t in v]))
```

Note that there's no need to assume nodes are integers.

Following this, you can see:

```
>>> g.edges()
[(nan, nan),
 ('AAAD', 'BBDD'),
 ('AAAD', nan),
 ('MMCC', nan),
 ('MMCC', 'AAAD'),
 ('BBDD', nan),
 ('KKLL', 'BBDD'),
 ('KKLL', nan),
 ('KKLL', 'AAFF'),
 ('KKLL', 'AAAD'),
 ('KKLL', 'MMCC'),
 ('AAFF', nan),
 ('AAFF', 'AAAD')]

​
```

Answer (score 21):

Actually, the Graph can simply be initialized by a dictionary. 
In this case:

```
g = nx.DiGraph(d)
```

will return the graph you want.